# Auth0 lock with Angular 1.5.8 and Webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack, auth0

I'm porting my Angular app from gulp over to Webpack and ES6. I'm using auth0 for authentication, and following the tutorial from auth0 here:

https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angularjs

My versions are:

- angular 1.5.8
- angular-lock 1.0.1
- auth0-lock 10.2.2

What I'm strugling with is this error I get when I'm loading up my app:

```
Failed to instantiate module app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module auth0.lock due to:
Error: Auth0Lock must be loaded.
```

I have a libraries.js file where I import all my dependencies:

```
import 'auth0-lock';
import 'angular-lock';
import 'angular-jwt';
```

and in my index.js I have the following setup:

```js
import './libraries';
import './app/home/home-component';
import './app/shared/security/authService';

module.exports = angular
    .module('app',
        ['ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'auth0.lock', 'angular-jwt', 'app.homeModule', 'shared.authModule'])
    .config(configFunction)
    .run(runFunction);
```

I have tried adding this plugin in my webpack.config.js with no luck:

```js
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  Auth0Lock: "auth0-lock",
}),
```

Any ideas of how I can make my Auth0Lock be loaded before the angular-lock loads? I thought that was going to happen since I important it first, but apperantly not.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe auth0-angular looks for Auth0Lock in the window object. Try changing the name of the global variable by changing to:

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    "window.Auth0Lock": "auth0-lock"
}),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the source code for *angular-lock.js* the exports are given as:

```
exports.default = Auth0Lock;
```

Hence the solution is to add a *'default'* to the ProvidePlugin in your webpack.config:

```
plugins: [          
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({

        Auth0Lock: ['auth0-lock','default'],
    })
],
```

I have tested this approach and it works as expected.