# Auth0 with Angular 1.5.8 and webpack

Tags: javascript, angularjs, webpack, auth0

I'm trying to integrate Auth0 into my Angular project that I'm bundling with webpack. When I launch the app I get the error:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module auth0.lock due to:
Error: Auth0Lock must be loaded.
```

My Config.js looks like:

```
import 'auth0-lock';
import 'angular-lock';
import 'angular-jwt';

import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import loginController from 'components/login/login.controller';
import authService from 'shared/auth/auth.service';


const app = angular.module('app',[uiRouter, 'auth0.lock', 'angular-jwt']);

app.config(($stateProvider, lockProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) => {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

    $stateProvider
        .state('login',{
            url:'/login',
            template: require('components/login/login.view.html'),
            controller: loginController,
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        })

    lockProvider.init({
        clientID: 'xxx',
        domain: 'xxx'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
});

app.service('authService',authService);

export default app;
```

And my index.js is

```
import angular from 'angular';
import appModule from './config';
angular.bootstrap(document, [appModule.name]);

run.$inject = ['$rootScope', 'authService', 'lock'];

function run($rootScope, authService, lock) {
    // Put the authService on $rootScope so its methods
    // can be accessed from the nav bar
    $rootScope.authService = authService;

    // Register the authentication listener that is
    // set up in auth.service.js
    authService.registerAuthenticationListener();

    // Register the synchronous hash parser
    lock.interceptHash();

    console.log('success');
}
```

I've read on a few places that setting window.Auth0Lock in the webpack config would fix it, but still no luck.

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    "window.Auth0Lock" : "auth0-lock"
}),
```

My problem is exactly the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39300263/auth0-lock-with-angular-1-5-8-and-webpack), but alas it remains unanswered. I would appricate any help.

Edit: The below solution doesn't seem to solve my problem and I'm still stuck. I believe I'm requiring all the required dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I do need lock.min.js, and when I tried to require it in my config file webpack would throw up. I also tried downloading and requiring the distributable, but that also was giving me problems. I gave up and now I'm referencing the CDN directly on my index.html. I think you can use webpack script-loader as well.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.5/lock.min.js"></script>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps.